# LINQ to XML not returning data

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So I have a simple XML Doc like this:

```xml
<Xml>
    <Node1></Node1>
    <Node2></Node2>
    ...
    <Node10></Node10>
        <Node10Stuff1></Node10Stuff1>
        <Node10Stuff2></Node10Stuff2>
    <Node11></Node11>
</Xml>
```

Since I'm getting the XML Using a post, I'm assigning it my `XDocument` like so:

```cs
XDocument xd;    
using(StringReader s = new StringReader(postXml))
{
     xd = XDocument.Load(s);
}
```

And here is my LINQ query:

```cs
var q = from c in xd.Root.Elements("Xml")
        select c;

foreach(var a in q)
{
     String node1= a.Element("Node1").ToString();
     ...etc...
}
```

But my foreach loop is always empty. Shouldnt my query be returning all of the nodes? At least the children of `<Xml>`?

Comment: Does your xml have a namespace?, could be causing an issue if it has as your code isn't referencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xd.Root` is already the `<Xml>` element - you're currently looking for `<Xml>` elements *below* that, which is why you're not finding anything.

It looks like you don't even need the `foreach` loop, just:

```
var root = xd.Root;

String node1 = (string) root.Element("Node1");
// etc
```

Comment: So then how would I get the Node10 children, using this method?

Comment: @Tonnie: You'd use `root.Element("Node10").Elements()`. I suggest you read up on LINQ to XML - there are various books and tutorials around; Stack Overflow is good for specific questions, but not for learning a technology overall.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the exact syntax, but you're looking for something like `Root.Elements()`. "Xml" is your root.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var q = from c in xd.Descendants("Xml")
        select c;

foreach(var a in q)
{
    String node1= a.Element("Node1").ToString();
    ...etc...
}
```